# Angular: render hyperlink in component if user provide click callback

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that has output `clickEvent`

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Output()
  clickEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

in HTML template I want to render hyperlink if that event bounded to callback

```
<a *ngIf="clickEvent bounded" >data</a>
<span *ngIf="!clickEvent bounded" >data</span>


<my></my> // should render span

<my (clickEvent)="doSomething()"></my> should render a
```

so how to check for event binding?

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to add an input boolean**

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() isHrefLink:Boolean = false;
  @Output()
  clickEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

**Template:**

```
<a *ngIf="isHrefLink" >data</a>
<span *ngIf="!isHrefLink" >data</span>
```

**How to use:**

```
<my></my> 

<my isHrefLink="true" (clickEvent)="doSomething()"></my>
```

Comment: is it possible to do without declare extra variable?

Comment: I don't prefer, clean code should be like this, clean and stupid code, it will be easier to understand and find bugs in future